# Do I need to study ODE in order to understand Fourier series and Fourier Transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm a self study in math, computer vision and machine learning. I just finished partial derivative and has no background in Ordinary differential equation(ODE). Do I need to study ODE in order to understand Fourier series and Fourier Transform? The Fourier series and Fourier Transform appears in my computer vision class and I feel unfamiliar with some notations.

maybe ODE will also benefit when I study deep learning too?

Comment: What do you mean by "I just finished partial derivative"?

Comment: I just finished my study in multivariable calculus on topic partial derivative. I say it then you guy knows my math level. then you can give me a proper advice.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I have misread and I thought you were talking about partial differential equaitons.

Comment: Fourrier analysis can be used to study differential equations.  So, there may be some applications covered in class that you do not grasp.  However there are many other applications that are unrelated.  You could probably get some extra help on the few of diff eq that come up.  What is central to the subject are integrals with complex exponentials.  Become very comfortable with the complex numbers and complex exponentials.

Comment: I fully agree with all what Doug M just said. Moreover, don't spend to much time on Fourier Series. As you are application oriented, nowadays, it's Fourier Transform that has a big importance, even a central role in domains like Signal (and also Image) Processing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice but I feel confusing. I'm not familier of what you guy are saying, so, in conclusion what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the reason why differential equations are studied to some extent before you get into Fourier series is that Fourier series are used in understanding the heat equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \text{constant} \cdot \sum_k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_k^2}
$$
and the wave equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \text{constant} \cdot \sum_k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_k^2}
$$
and some more exotic equations than those.

You can understand a lot about Fourier series without that, but understanding what they're good for requires that.

The book on Fourier series and Fourier integrals by Dym and McKean has lots of examples of what they're used for.  (But it's not the best place to learn theory of integration, the topic of one of the chapters, and the omission of everything involving the use of generalized functions (such as Dirac's delta and its derivatives) might reasonably be objected to by some.)

Comment: So.. should I study ODE before Fourier series? for good understanding?

Comment: isn't wave involve in computer vision too? like frequency and Fourier Transform? please give me advice. I'm a newbie

Comment: @user3270418 : The list of applied-math topics in which Fourier series and other types of Fourier transforms are used is very very long. $\qquad$